# Pylint - "Using the global statement"

Tags: python, global-variables, warnings, pylint

I'm trying to work on my current python program being very conscious of pylint warnings, so while I realize I can simply turn off the warning, I want to be sure that there is not a more desirable solution before I do.

My current section of the code is my logging code.  I have a function `init()` that sets up handlers and attaches them to the root logger, and a function `set_console_level(level)` that sets the level at which console messages are reported (DEBUG, INFO, etc..):

```
_CONSOLE_OUT = NONE

def init():
    """Set up the error handlers for the root logger"""
    console_out = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_out.setLevel(logging.INFO)  #Show info messages for now
    #...
    logging.root.addHandler(console_out)
    global _CONSOLE_OUT
    _CONSOLE_OUT = console_out

    #Rest of function sets up more handlers similarly
init()

def set_console_level(level):
    """Change the level at which console messages are printed"""
    assert __CONSOLE_OUT is not None #Set in init
    _CONSOLE_OUT.setLevel(level)
```

As far as I could tell from my reading, this is the way to do this.  The line `global _CONSOLE_OUT` is needed in order to write to the module-level variable.  However, when I run pylint on this file I get the warning `W: 15,4:init: Using the global statement`.  Is there a way to avoid this warning?  A better way to approach this problem?

(Please don't say `global _CONSOLE_OUT #pylint: disable=W****` without giving justification)

Comment: double underscore is unnecessary you could use `_` instead or just leave it out of  the `__all__` list. CAPS_LOCK is usually reserved for constants. See [pep-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize there is a distinction between constant and non-constant module level variables.  (Another issue with changing everything that pylint suggests)  Though the console log is meant to be constant, in a sense.  
And, yeah, I should edit this to single _, as I used in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create it at import time:

```
_console_out = ConsoleHandler()
```

where `ConsoleHandler` is a factory function or *your* class that create and setup the handler.

Comment: @Retsam: You could refactor the part that creates handler into a separate function. It is a common idiom to initialize a singleton object at import time e.g., json, logging (root logger), random modules use it. I've updated the code.

Comment: Ah.  It would be good to clarify in the answer that ConsoleHandler() is a function that I would write, and not just the wrong name for the existing object constructor as I took it to be.

Answer (score 1):

This is a weird pattern to set items outside of the methods scope. It will lead to problems later because you won't know where global variables are being set from.

Your code is also relying on the order of execution of methods to set variables that - presumably - other parts of your code rely on. This may cause problems later if you forget to call an `init()` especially when importing things (of course you could always stick it in `__init__.py`, but that's not the point here).

Given those, I think another way around is to create a class and set the variable inside the class (giving it another namespace); or if you want to keep it as is, as Sebastian suggested return the configuration variables.

You can return a tuple and then unpack it to create your global variables if you need to set more than one.

```
>>> def foo():
...   return "hello","world"
...
>>> a,b = foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I thought of looking at the code (and with Burhan Khalid's answer) is that there's no reason that my `init()` code *has* to be in a function at all, since I simply mean for it to be run once when imported. I believe the only reason I originally did this was so that the handler variables wouldn't be module-level.

So instead my code could simply be

```
_CONSOLE_OUT = logging.StreamHandler()
_CONSOLE_OUT.setLevel(logging.INFO)  #Show info messages for now
#...
logging.root.addHandler(_CONSOLE_OUT)

#...

def set_console_level(level):
    """Change the level at which console messages are printed"""
    assert _CONSOLE_OUT is not None #Set at root
    _CONSOLE_OUT.setLevel(level)
```